# Converting to decimal in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, radix

I am asking for an help to write a code doing the following in Matlab:

(1) I have a column vector `A` of dimension `nx1` listing the `n` digits after the comma of a number `B` in **base 4** between `0` and `1`

What I mean by base 4 is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternary_numeral_system)

Example

```
n=18
A=[1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2]' %representing B=0.121212121212121212
```

(2) I want to convert `B` to **base 10** (decimal representation) and store the obtained decimal number `C` in a `1x1` matrix

Could you help me to understand how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
C = base2dec(char(A(:).'+'0'), 4)*4^-numel(A);
```

This converts the digits to an integer in base `4` and then divides by the appropriate power of `4`.

Take into account that `C` will be limited by `double` precision, so some decimals may be lost. If you want more precision you need to use symbolic variables.

Comment: Thanks, but I think my question wasn't clear, sorry. You code gives me 0.1212 which seems to be B (with only 4 digits after the comma) that is in base 4. I want to convert B in base 10.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "base". Anyway, the result `C` has more than 4 decimals. It's just that Matlab only shows 4 by default. Try `format long`

Comment: Sorry, now I see what you mean. I'll edit my answer when I get to a computer

Comment: @user3285148 Edited

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you have the decimal place in there to slow that you want powers less than 1.  Here is a brute force loop to do it.

```
C = 0;
for x = 1:n
    C = res + A(x) * 4 ^ (-x);
end
C = 0.399999999994179
```

Here is another way

```
exp = (-1 * (1:18))';
C = sum(A .* 4 .^ exp);
C = 0.399999999994179
```

Using your link as a guide let's look at the number in decimal of `15`.  This corresponds to the base 4 of `33`.  In this case `A = [3 3]` and `exp = [1 0]`.  This results in:

```
A = [3 3];
exp = [1 0];
C = sum(A .* 4 .^ exp);
C = 15
```

Your link has a [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix#Conversion_among_bases) explaining the basics of conversions.